# Datastore javaclient giving no java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, protocol-buffers

We are using datastore java client :

```
compile group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'google-cloud-datastore', version: '0.11.2-beta'
```

But we are getting the following error while executing any query :

```
WARN  [2017-04-11 19:43:33,556] [ ] org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@bfe47a8: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage.newBuilderForType(Lcom/google/protobuf/AbstractMessage$BuilderParent;)Lcom/google/protobuf/Message$Builder;
! java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage.newBuilderForType(Lcom/google/protobuf/AbstractMessage$BuilderParent;)Lcom/google/protobuf/Message$Builder;
! at com.google.protobuf.SingleFieldBuilderV3.getBuilder(SingleFieldBuilderV3.java:142)
! at com.google.protobuf.RepeatedFieldBuilderV3.addBuilder(RepeatedFieldBuilderV3.java:413)
! at com.google.datastore.v1.Query$Builder.addKindBuilder(Query.java:1713)
! at com.google.cloud.datastore.StructuredQuery.toPb(StructuredQuery.java:945)
! at com.google.cloud.datastore.StructuredQuery.populatePb(StructuredQuery.java:924)
! at com.google.cloud.datastore.QueryResultsImpl.sendRequest(QueryResultsImpl.java:72)
! at com.google.cloud.datastore.QueryResultsImpl.<init>(QueryResultsImpl.java:57)
! at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.run(DatastoreImpl.java:84)
! at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.run(DatastoreImpl.java:75)
! at com.nis.userService.core.managed.DeltaContactConsumer.start(DeltaContactConsumer.java:33)
```

Sample can be found at : https://gist.github.com/Saurabh111191/2afb12dc13e71c361291c1bf3cc0b4f8

We have tried using other client libraries also like objectify , but getting the same error.

Can someone help us out here?

Comment: have you tried using a simple example to test?

Comment: Most likely you have an incompatible version of protobuf JAR file. I would recommend double checking your class path and do any necessary cleanup and try again.